# How do I only keep the date and year for columns, and set to the right format?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am cleaning a dataset for analysis. I don't know how to deal with these two columns of time/date data. How do I keep only the year/date and set it to the right format for analysis? They are currently treated as categorical data.

[image: time data]

Comment: See `as.Date()` or `as.POSIXct()` to covert the string into either a Date or a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help

```
df$date_last_pur <- as.Date(df$date_last_pur,format='%m/%d/%Y')
df$date_sign_up <- as.Date(df$date_sign_up,format='%m/%d/%Y')
```